# Magento 2 Google recaptcha issue in multiple websites

Tags: magento2, recaptcha

I have installed **Google Recaptcha extension(msp/recaptcha)** using composer.
It's installed successfully and working in default website and not working in other websites.
When I check the console it's giving 404 Page not found error

> `535dc1ddcd538f1a68d2c8d093103e2f.min.js:120 GET https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.min.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)`

Enabled js minification and merge for all the websites but in default website Recaptcha is loading with `https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js`

For other websites it's trying to load `api.min.js` which is not exist.

If I disable JS minification and merge then Recaptcha is working for all the websites.

Comment: Did you get any solution for this?